# replacing asyncio with concurent.futures

Tags: python, python-asyncio

asyncio is causing issues on my spyder IDE => would like to replace it with concurent.futures library

how can I replace the below code relying only on concurent.futures library
`asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(api(message))`

exact function looks as follows

```
def async_loop(api, message):
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(api(message))
```

Comment: "*asyncio is causing issues*" Please [edit] to clarify what exact issues is it causing and _why_ you think replacing it with concurrent.futures would solve the problem. It might be an XY problem, because spyder is an IDE and IDEs shouldn't normally affect a package's functionality.

Comment: I am getting error "There is no current event loop in thread Tread-xx", which I am unable to fix. I would prefer to simply use an alternative library to execute the above.

Answer (score 1):

As written, you're starting up the event loop only until a particular task completes (which may or may not launch or wait on other tasks), and blocking until it completes. The *only* reason it's a task is because it needs to use `async` functions, those can only run in an event loop, and while running, they may launch other tasks or wait on other awaitables, and while waiting, the event loop can do other tasks.

In short, if not for the need to be an async task running in a non-async context, this would just be:

```
def async_loop(api, message):
    return api(message)
```

which calls `api` and waits for it to complete.

Really, that's it. If the things `api` does or calls need to run some tasks asynchronously, without blocking on them immediately, you'd have some global executor, e.g.

```
executor = concurrent.Futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
```

which would be used to launch tasks with:

```
fut = executor.submit(callable, 'arg1', 'arg2', kwarg1='somevalue')
```

and, when the result of the task is needed, someone would call:

```
value = fut.result()
```

on it (which would block if it wasn't done yet, return the result if it completed without an exception, or raise the exception it died with if it died with an exception).

Whenever you no longer need the executor, you just call `.shutdown()` on it and it will wait for all outstanding tasks to complete. That's it.

---

As a side-note, the error you're experiencing is part of why they've deprecated `get_event_loop()` in 3.10 (and discouraged it since 3.7). In all likelihood, the simplest solution to your problem (avoiding a switch to threads, because all that means is you've got new problems) is to use [the much simpler high-level API, `asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) (introduced in 3.7), which creates an event loop, runs the task in it to completion, does reasonable cleanup, then returns the result:

```
def async_loop(api, message):
    return asyncio.run(api(message))
```

There's also the `asyncio.get_running_loop` function (that is the exact replacement for `get_event_loop`) which you use when an event loop already exists (which you should typically be aware of; event loops don't pop into existence in given thread on their own, so you should know if you launched one; in this case you hadn't, so `asyncio.run` is the correct one to use).